# Handling JDBC closed Connections

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jdbc, database-connection

I want to automatically reconnect and resend the last SQL Query if a connection closed (e.g. on the db server, not because I will close it).

I know I could do `connection.isValid()` (which is just `SELECT 1` in most driver implementations) before sending each query, but this is wasteful. I will add a round-trip delay to every single one of my queries.

What I wanted was something more like:

- Sends a query to the database
- If the connection is down reconnect and resend the same query
- If can't reconnect, throw the connection closed `Exception`.

Are there any recommendations regarding this? I can't imagine I am the first one to want something like it.

I am thinking about making a wrapper around my driver's `java.sql.Connection` and run this algorithm behind the scenes, but if there's something out there yet I would appreciate to not have to reinvent the whell (I tried to google it, but couldn't find anything).

PS: I don't want a connection pool because I will use this inside an AWS Lambda instance and all the connection pools I know would just run `isValid` before each query.

Comment: Fascinating. My advice: *just run `isValid` before each query.* Trying to detect after the fact, is going to be **worse**.

Comment: Overcome your aversion and use a connection pool, e.g. Apache DBCP. Takes care of all that for you, and *not* by calling `isValid()` before each query, but typically by issuing a `SELECT `1 to the database. The advice to run `isValid()` before each query is poor practice: it amounts to trying to predict the future. The connection can still fail afterwards, and you still have to deal with that. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: @user207421 Ummm, usually `isValid()` does use `SELECT 1` against the database. And that is also the method a connection pool will use to validate a connection (but I do agree with you that letting the connection pool do it for you is better).

Comment: @user207421 most JDBC driver implementations call `SELECT 1` inside `isValid()`

Comment: I will be running this inside an AWS Lambda, the less libraries I have the better for cold starts. Besides AWS Lambda instances can only have 1 connection, so it will be a connection pool for just 1 connection... so it feels like a heavy solution for a specific problem.

Comment: Trying to test **after** you've made your query is still going to cost more (both in runtime and your own implementation).

Comment: This problem is very related with AWS Lambda, because a Lambda instance will go to sleep after executing its invocation. Once there's a new invocation the Lambda will be woken up and the connection I created and cached (since it takes some time to create a connection and we pay for time in Lambda) could be down already.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch could you elaborate more on why will it cost more? As far as I see, on the moment I try to execute a query with a connection down, it will fail (same time that `isValid` will take to fail). Then reconnecting will be the same time as well, so where will it cost more?

Comment: Because you will have to write and maintain that code (which already exists in isValid), and you will then have to manually maintain the connection and reconnect and requery (and write that code too).

Comment: hmmm makes sense...too bad no one has made this as a small library before

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I raised this issue in HikariCP before here: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1304 and since Lambda freezes, even connection pools can fail to serve me

Comment: If your container freezes, your own code would freeze too. You need to look into the root causes of your "freezes".

Comment: Lambda freezes by design.

Comment: I will go with `isValid` for now, maybe test how HIkariCP behaves on this.

Comment: Testing your connection each time is really overkill (especially given connection pools will do this for you before leasing out the connection). Just execute the query and be prepared to handle failures.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You don't *have* to 'test *after* you have made your query'. It will throw an exception, or succeed. No timing window problem there.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yeah,but since I will be using a connection pool just to test a connection, I might just do it myself and not have a connection pool at all.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own wrapper around `java.sql.Connection` that catches errors and retries statements after re-establishing a broken connection sounds appealing, but then you'd also need to write your own `PreparedStatement`, and so on, right?

It might be a better idea to centralize all your JDBC calls in a few places in your application, i.e., write your own (thin) abstraction for JDBC calls. Then you can put your retry magic in one spot.

I would definitely use connection pooling. Any connection pool that is worth its salt can be configured to *not* send a query to the server. Even if you cannot avoid that, it is *much* cheaper than opening and closing a database connection.

Comment: What do you mean by `be configured to not send a query to the server`? Why would I want that? Are you saying there are connection pools that on a connection failure will auto-retry?

Comment: I meant that you probably can configure most connection pools to send no `SELECT 1` to the server automatically. Sorry for the sloppiness. I had the impression you were concerned about that. I don't know if there are connection pools that automatically re-establish broken connections, but it wouldn't surprise me. At any rate, I want to encourage you to use a connection pool.

Comment: I wanted to use a connection pool, but I will be running my code on AWS lambda and this complicates matters a bit. AWS Lambda freezes the container when the code returns and it has to return in some seconds or it does timeout. So it's basically a single thread model. If I set a connection pool, it would be a connection pool of 1 connection, that will have its management threads freezed by AWS Lambda. When it unfreezes the timings will be wrong. It will probably work, just print timing errors at each new invocation. So I thought that I could make matters simpler to check `isValid` myself.